# Access KeyChain from PackageMaker

Tags: macos, keychain, packagemaker

Is it possible to store certificates into the key chain as part of installation created with PackageMaker? I would like to provide an installation which inserts the certificates into the key chain on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've founded the solution for importing certificates as a part of installation.
The solution includes performing following steps:

1. add **certs** folder (contains the certificates we wish to import) into the installation. The certs folder is extracted on the specified path (defined as CERT_PATH variable)
2. create a shell script (also included into the installation to be extracted), which performs the import of certificates into the keychain. The script looks similar to:

   `CERT_PATH = "/Applications/MyApp/certs"`

   `security add-certificates $CERT_PATH/mycert1.crt`

   `security add-certificates $CERT_PATH/mycert2.crt`

The script is called ***postflight*** (more about Package Maker and scripts at [Using PackageMaker to run a script on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640701/using-packagemaker-to-run-a-script-on-install))