# When postupgrade is indeed called in MacOSX pkg?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, post-install

Good morning, I am reading about the prepared scripts in MacOSX to use when creating a pkg for my application.

In particular, I have some doubts how to make sure that postupgrade script is used.
What I read till now is:
from [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/06/01/understanding-payload-free-packages/)

> The postupgrade script is run after files have been installed and before the postflight script if one is defined. This script is run only if the component has been previously installed. If the script does not return an exit status of zero, Installer will declare the installation has failed.

Ok then it seems that postupgrade will just run in automatic when an upgrade is done. BUT...from `man pkgbuild`, section `--scripts scripts-path`

> Archive the entire contents of scripts-path as the package scripts. If this directory contains scripts named preinstall and/or postinstall, these will be run as the top-level scripts of the package. If you want to run scripts for specific bundles, you must specify those in a component property list; see more at COMPONENT PROPERTY LIST.  Any other files under scripts-path will be used only if the top-level or component-specific scripts invoke them.

So, it seems I should add it to the component.plist, since they do not say anything about `postupgrade`. BUT it seems strange, I would put there more specific script, not the `postupgrade` script.

Reading more, I found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640701/using-packagemaker-to-run-a-script-on-install) that refers to [this](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), where there is written:

> To determine whether a Package has already been installed or not, Installer.app is having a look at the content of the following directory: /Library/Receipts. If there's a file named PackageName.pkg within it, then the Package has already been installed, otherwise it's the first install.

Well, my application leaves no pkg file there, but yes it is present in the InstallHistory.plist.

Well, finally the question: should I set the upgrade script somewhere, for example in the component.plist file? The last link seems to be out of date, something has changed? How can I put a pkg file inside `/Library/Receipts`? Or better, how can be sure if my installation is indeed an installation and not an upgrade, or viceversa?

Thanks everyone, I am a bit confused...

Comment: What does dubt mean?

Comment: Sorry, the word was "doubt" (mispelling). But it was not allowed in titles. I edited it :)

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue